# Found nil while unwrapping an Optional val

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I know there are a lot of questions related to this but I did not found an answer to fix my code.

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
```

class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController {

```
// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var billTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var zeroPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tenPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var twentyPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var splitNumberLabel: UILabel!

// Variables
var tipSelected: Double = 0.0
var splitAmmount: Double = 0.0
var splitNumber: Int = 2
var totalBill: Double = 0.0

var tipText: String?


@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
    billTextField.endEditing(true)
    if sender.currentTitle == "0%" {
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = true
        tenPctButton.isSelected = false
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
        tipSelected = 0.0
    } else if sender.currentTitle == "10%" {
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
        tenPctButton.isSelected = true
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
        tipSelected = 0.1
    } else if sender.currentTitle == "20%" {
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
        tenPctButton.isSelected = false
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = true
        tipSelected = 0.2
    }
    tipText = sender.currentTitle!
}

@IBAction func billTextEdited(_ sender: UITextField) {
    totalBill = Double(sender.text!)!
}

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    billTextField.endEditing(true)
    splitNumberLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", sender.value)
    splitNumber = Int(splitNumberLabel.text!)!
}

@IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if totalBill > 0 {
        splitAmmount = (totalBill * (tipSelected + 1)) / Double(splitNumber)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toResultVC", sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
```

> here I get the error in any of the two lines

```
    ***destinationVC.totalLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", splitAmmount)***
    ***destinationVC.settingsLbl.text = "Split between \(splitNumberLabel.text) with \(tipText)"***
}
```

}

Now here are the debug area showing all the variables get a value

[DEBUG AREA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcDwA.jpg)

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Check that your IBOutlets are set in the storyboard. Or set a breakpoint and examine the members of destinationVC.

Comment: thank you for your help, as you said I checked the IBOutlets and apparentely everything was fine, so I decided to delete all the IBOutles and create them again and then start working ok